# How to overwrite getter and setter in javascript for all properties?

Tags: javascript

How to overwrite getter and setter in javascript for all properties and not only the properties that are known in advance. I have seen a lot of post that do that for a property that is known at the moment of writing the class for example :

```
var obj = { get test(){return 'ya'}}
obj.test
==> "ya"
```

But I would like to be able to overwrite getter and setter for all properties of the object, for example as soon as I call `obj.toto` or `obj.titi` I want to call my custom getter/setter, but I can not now in advance the properties that will be added to `obj`,`obj` is like a container of whatever we want.

Comment: You could use a proxy, but whether this is the right choice depends on the problem you're trying to solve.